# Search exact words in elastichsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Using elasticseach, I want to search all documents with two words.

I use:

`{ "query": { "match": { "text": "word1 word2" } } }`

but instead of having documents with word1 and word2, i have documents with word1 or word2.
¿how can i search docs with word1 AND word2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `operator` in the query.

> The operator parameter can be set to or or and to control the boolean
> clauses (defaults to or).

```
POST test_index/_doc
{"text":"word1"}
POST test_index/_doc
{"text":"word2"}
POST test_index/_doc
{"text":"word1 word2"}


GET test_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": {
        "query": "word1 word2",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-boolean

[image]